Use DeferredResult for specific endpoint in openApi and springboot3
Is there a way to use DeferredResult (or another wrapper) for specific endpoint using contract first approach?
Following solutions are not ideal for my case :

Customizing the mustache template is extra work.
Using the code to generate the specification would break the methodology of working.

Not sure if it can be achieved using vendor extensions.
Tried **responseWrapper ** which wraps all endpoints and that is not what I need.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have investigated this for myself, and it isnt.
If you look at the existing template for say "apiDelegate.mustache" which is inside the openapi-generator JAR file. It simply  wraps all operations with "responseWrapper" directly from the config, with no additional logic around it. I think the main use case is for where you might for example be using a totally different REST library etc. There is no logic to conditionally apply things. So I am duplicating the whole template and will add in some conditional logic myself.
I think a good enhancement to their library, would be to configure an additional vendor extension and allow  the response wrapper to be overridden on an operation by operation basis.
** Additional info*
I think using CompletableFuture is better than DefferedResult, but it has the same problem of only being able to be toggled on or off for all.
I have extended the delegate template to just allow me to toggle it on a per operation basis.

Using DefferredResult would be benefical if you need to set a timeout for the operation and less breaking head to manage it yourself, most of the case deferred result used in combination with completable future. I am not in a favor to custom the mustache because you need to maintain it as long as spring add new improvement to that template. the thing which is confused is that you can acheive the desired result using code first approach but not contract first approach while both approach must have same capabilities. I hope they will adapt this.
